# If $f : [a, b] \to X$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ show that $\exists$ $g : [c, d] \to X$ which is also a path from $x$ to $y$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> If $f : [a, b] \to X$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ show that there exists $g : [c, d] \to X$ which is also a path from $x$ to $y$

Now I know that $[a, b]$ is homeomorphic to $[c, d]$, hence there must exist a homeomorphism $h : [c, d] \to [a, b]$. I'm assuming I'm going to have to use $h$ to prove the existence of $g$, but I'm not sure how I could do that.

I was thinking that if $h$ was also a path (which we can't be sure if it is), then $g = f \circ h : [c, d] \to X$ would be the desired continuous path. But the problem with that is that we need $h$ to be a path such that $h(c) = a$ and $h(d) = b$.

I'm not sure how to continue the proof. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $h: [c,d]\to[a,b]$ such that $h(x) = \frac{b-a}{d-c}(x-c)+a$. Then $h$ is a homeomorphism with $h(c)=a, h(d)=b$.

Comment: Forget about $X$ for now. Come up with the simplest mapping of [a,b] to [c,d]. Graph paper may be helpful.